# jQuery - Reload Bootstrap Popover Window with Load() on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I looked around and tried many different options to get this working but somehow I cant find a solution.

I have a boostrap `popover` window that will `load()` external url.

Everything works OK when I click the popup button first time but once I close the popover, the query function will not reload on click once the window has been closed.

Ideally, the `popover` window will be reloaded with fresh data every time the `popover` is called by a `click`.

my button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pop-class"
                data-container="body"
                data-toggle="popover"
                data-placement="left"
                id="{{ instance.id }}"></a>
```

Here is my script

```
$('.pop-class').popover({
        html: true,
        title: function() {
            return $("#my-head").html();
        },
        content: function() {
            $('#hidden-input').val(this.id);
            var id = this.id + '#container';
            return $( "#my-content" ).load( "/mypage/"+id );
        }

    });
```

**Update:**

Scenario:

This app has an external html form that the user can load as needed. As this form is dynamic and will allow the user to also update current data the form is loaded on a fly with the instance data.

As the user can close the `popover` at any time and return back later, the `load()` function should always load new data based on the instance `ID` or load a empty form for new entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TOTALLY UPDATED ANSWER**

If I understood you task, I offer you not to use a bootstrap (it's not that it is designed for).

There is a snippet based on JQuery Ui. ([JQuery UI Dialog docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/))

There is a button that opens a dialog with an `<iframe>` that loading some web page each time dialog opens.

If you do not need an iframe, you could load any other contents instead.

```js
$(function () {
    
    // Setting up the dialog
    $('#dialog1').dialog({
        // Hidden for now
        autoOpen: false,
        // Title
        title: 'My External Form',
        // Width in px
        width: 790,
        // Dialog close event handler
        close: function() {
            // Looking for an iframe inside it
            $(this).find('iframe').
                // Clearing its contents
                attr('src', 'about:blank');
        }
    });

    // Looking for our dialog
    $('#dialog1').
        // Looking for JQuery UI initialized dialog (up the DOM tree)
        closest('.ui-dialog').
        // Looking for dialog title (down the DOM tree)
        find('.ui-dialog-title').
        // Prepending the title with an Font Awesome icon
        prepend('<i class="fa fa-list fa-lg grey"></i>');

    // Subscribing to the click on the button
    $('button.show-dialog').click(function () {
        // Caching the JQuery button object
        var $button = $(this);
        // Getting ID of the associated dialog from 'data-dialog' attribute
        var dialogId = $button.data('dialog');
        // If there is an ID
        if (typeof(dialogId) != 'undefined')
        {
            // Getting a JQuery UI dialog by ID
            var $dialog = $('#' + dialogId);
            // Opening the dialog
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            // Loading a content to the iframe
            $dialog.find('iframe').attr('src', 'http://apple.com');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.dialog
{
    display: none;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar i.fa {
    margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.ui-dialog .dialog.ui-dialog-content
{
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dialog iframe
{
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="container">
        <button class="show-dialog" data-dialog="dialog1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg orange">My Button</i></button>

        <div class="dialog" id="dialog1">
            <iframe id="dialog1-frame" name="dialog1-frame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying and trying and cant get it work, your code wont even open the `popover`. Can you please recheck the script?

Comment: My code is not about opening a popover. It's about loading content by your function when opening a popover. You'd better provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with you code.

Comment: almost there, made the correct changes and the window is loading, the issue now is that the `popover` is small and I cant see anything inside the window. The good news is that I'm getting 200 response in every click!

Comment: the data is loading inside the page (bottom) instead of the `popover` any suggestions? Also, is there a way to `clear` the data if the 'popover` is closed?

Comment: Also, the data is only loading on repeated click and will not load on first click, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not have such good imagination :-) You did not provide code to fix. What do you mean by `clear` the data? Call `$(...).text('');` to clear the contents of some element.

Comment: While I still need to do some work on my project, I do appreciate your help and I did send a couple of up votes your way. Thanks again for the effort!

Comment: Thank you! If you didn't solve your problem – please provide a snippet, so we could see an actual problem and deal with it.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to do something that is bootstrap not designed for. Bootstrap do not require such scripts for popover functionality. Do you really need to do that with bootstrap? I'll provide you a solution with JQuery and JQuery UI little bit later.

Comment: Vlad, I do have this in place http://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/74oh88zu/. It works OK! The only issue is resizing the `popover` window

Comment: @WayBehind 1. You are doing it wrong. It's not good to load all the html source of the page to a div. You'd better use an `<iframe>` instead. 2. Bootstrap Popover is not a popout window. It [designed](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples) to be shown near the button firstly.

Comment: Vlad, I'm only loading an update `form` that is used to update or add new data. It is not an entire page. The reason for that is that the page `dashboard` may be very busy and there is no need to load the `form` at the bottom of the page unless is requested. I also skipped `modal` windows as those will not be supported in bootstrap 4.

Comment: That being said, I will definitely look into your solution! Much appreciate your help!

Comment: BTW I have accepted your answer. You can also look at the updated JS Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/74oh88zu/

Comment: You JS won't work on real page in browser I think (not i JSFIddle). Many web-sites deny cross-domain AJAX requests to them. By the way, many sites do not allow to load them into '<iframe>` too. If you want to asynchronously load content from page located on different domain, you'll usually get an error.

Comment: I was trying to fix your JSFiddle and could not do that. Anyway you're doing it wrong. You've got a lot of JS managing your popover. But in documentation there is no such scripts. There are [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes) for your purpose. Modals are modal windows as you need I think.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I have been playing with your solution and I may use it for some parts of my project. So far, the only downfall I noticed is that the loaded `iframe` must be a fully rendered page. For example, with my `load()`, I can load or include html code that has not been rendered and it will display correctly. For example, I have an html form and the form is loaded and all `css styles` are applied after it has been loaded. With your solution, I need to load all `JS` and styles to render the html. Basically it must be a full web page and I was looking only for a way to load my form

Comment: @WayBehind Yes, it'll be a full web page loaded. You are trying to do something uncommon. It's not a usual case. What is your real goal you are trying to reach? Why do you need such dialog with contents from another web site? Anyway, you could load any content in my solution with your `load()` technique. But it's not good if you will load all the web page contents (with `<head>`, `<meta>`, `<script>`, `<style>` and other tags).

Comment: Vlad, I understand that sometimes it may not make sense and perhaps it is a wrong way of doing it and I may change it in the future. As of now, I just need to get something in place so I have a starting point. Here is a screen shot, perhaps it would give you an idea. Once again, your help and feedback is much appreciate! JD Fiddle screen: https://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/8L06ghf3/

Comment: Sorry, I looked at your screenshot and got tangled about what the question is for now.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to show you an actual screenshot of how the `popover` is used and why I didnt go with `Modal` or a `iFrame` for this situation. Perhaps all of those could be used with success :)

Comment: Ok, I see. But it could be more suitable to have your own form and not to load it from another place each time.